# jQuery "this" plus other selectors?

Tags: jquery, hover

Is it possible to combine `$(this)` with `$('.someclass')`?

Example: `$(this + ', .someclass').hover()`;

I am attempting to use the hover action to animate a non-descendent class. I want the class element to animate whether "it", aka $('.someclass') OR $(this) is hovered.

I'm hoping this can be done without creating 2 separate hover actions.

Comment: If `this` has an `id`, `$('#' + this.id + ', .someclass').hover();`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

```
$(this).add('.someClass').hover();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use selector context: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

```
$('+ .someclass', this).hover();
```

Here is a sample: Hover over the first sibling and second sibling's background color will be changed.

```js
$('.sibling1').hover(
  function() {
    $('+ .sibling2', this).css({"background":"#ff0"});
  },
  function() {
    $('+ .sibling2', this).css({"background":"#eee"});
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  padding:5px;
  background:#eee;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sibling1">Sibling 1</div>
<div class="sibling2">Sibling 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An other option would be to use jQuery `find()`

```
$(this).find('.someclass').hover();
```

Comment: This will look for `.someclass` as a child of `this`.  It's not the equivalent of `,` in a selector.